# PHP Email Not Working

Tags: email, ubuntu-10.04, php

I've recently installed my server on VPS, PHP mail is not working, I've tryed everywhere but I can't get it to work.  If it is not a syntax error I would appreciate if someone could help with setting PHP mail up. Im running ubuntu 10.04

My code is:

```
     $ToEmail = 'my@email.com'; 

     $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form '; 
     $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
     $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
     $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
     $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br>"; 
     $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
     $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message: ".nl2br($_POST["message"])."<br>"; 
     $MESSAGE_BODY .= "IP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']";
     mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
```

Comment: Please give more information. What have you tried, what kinds of errors are you receiving, what do you suspect, etc. Also please talk about the mail server, not just the php setup.

Comment: @Karl Code you posted here has extra quote in  second last line. Is this part of code? As you can see by formatting, it shouldn't.

Comment: Since this is a VPS, have you tired sending mail from the command line? Try doing that and throw in the -v switch to get verbose messages about what is happening. Then check your mail logs (normally in `/var/log/mail.log` or similar name).

Comment: I will get back to you in just a sec after I try these.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GRBTfVh8 There is my log

Comment: run `lsof -i > firewallports.txt` and provide the results please,
the result will be in firewallports.txt make sure you remove any of your IP info we wont be responsible for you getting hacked

Comment: I only recently got my VPS and I didn't have LSOF installed -_- So that can't be the probably. I do suspect it could be to do with how the mail is configured. I havent got CMD line mail working yet. I'm using Sendmail and it just stalls.

Comment: You've got sendmail AND postfix installed. You can't have two different SMTP servers running at the same time. I'd recommend removing sendmail and sticking with postfix exclusively. It's by far easier to configure/maintain than sendmail.

Comment: Just got it to send mail on command line! PHP still isn't working though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the log you posted:

```
Jun 13 11:49:42 hedgehog postfix/master[12617]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
```

This should give you a clue if you are unable to connect to your server.

Comment: Hmm, any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: Find the process that is listening on port 25 and kill it. Then restart postfix.

Comment: Try:

sudo netstat --tcp --listening --program


.. Find the pid of the process and use `kill <pid>` to end it